# Duplicate entry ... for key 'PRIMARY' on many-to-many entity update using Entity Framework 6 with MySql

Tags: c#, mysql, entity-framework

In order to learn ASP.NET I decided to write my own blog in it. I'm using Entity Framework 6 and MySQL 5.6.21.

I have a BlogPost entity

```
public class BlogPost
{
    public BlogPost()
    {
        Comments = new HashSet<Comment>();
        BlogPostTags = new HashSet<BlogPostTag>();
    }

    public int BlogPostId { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [StringLength(150)]
    public string Title { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [StringLength(16777215)]
    public string Content { get; set; }

    public DateTime PublishTime { get; set; }
    public DateTime UpdateTime { get; set; }

    [StringLength(500)]
    public string Summary { get; set; }
    public string Author { get; set; }


    public virtual ICollection<Comment> Comments { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<BlogPostTag> BlogPostTags { get; set; } 
}
```

that has many-to-many relationship with BlogPostTag entity, which looks like this

```
public class BlogPostTag
{
    public BlogPostTag()
    {
        BlogPosts = new HashSet<BlogPost>();
    }

    [Key]
    [StringLength(50)]
    public string TagName { get; set; }

    public ICollection<BlogPost> BlogPosts { get; set; }

    public override int GetHashCode()
    {
        return TagName.GetHashCode();
    }
}
```

When I try to edit a post and I decide to add some tags to a BlogPost entity, EF6 throws an exception (which is just a MySQL exception propagated upwards): "Duplicate entry 'tag1' for key 'PRIMARY'". This happens only if 'tag1' already exists in database (= some blog post has/had this tag).

This is how I'm updating BlogPost entity:

```
public void EditBlogPost(BlogPost blogPost, string tags)
{
    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(tags))
    {
        var splitTags = tags.Split(';');

        foreach (var tag in splitTags)
        {
            blogPost.BlogPostTags.Add(new BlogPostTag() {TagName = tag});
        }
    }

    blogPost.UpdateTime = DateTime.Now;

    int bound = blogPost.Content.Length < 300 ? blogPost.Content.Length : 300;
    blogPost.Summary = blogPost.Content.Substring(0, bound) + "...";

    BlogPosts.Add(blogPost);

    SaveChanges();
}
```

This method is called from ASP.NET MVC controller. `tags` parameter is received from a POST and is a semicolon delimited string (e.g. `tag1;tag2;tag3`). `BlogPosts` is declared as `public DbSet<BlogPost> BlogPosts { get; set; }`

Is there a way to tell EF to first check if a tags already exists in a database and if so, use it instead of trying to insert a new one?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you have to progmatically check if there is something in blogposttag that exists already.

Something like
Blogposttag.firstordefault (x => x.tagname == name);

Then if that's null, then add that to the blog post tag. And if it isn't null, then you can skip the blogposttag.add() and just use that object in the blogpost entity.